# argparse conditional argument structure

Tags: python, argparse

I want to use argparse and have it so the number of arguments supplied determines which subroutine is executed.

For example, in the script below, I would like argparse to be able to execute the following:

```
dmsconvert.py 12.5
>>> (12, 30, 0)

dmsconvert.py 12 30 0.0
>>> 12.5
```

Instead, the only way I have been able to do this with argparse is to have an explicit option, i.e:

```
dmsconvert.py 12.5
>>> (12, 30, 0)

dmsconvert.py -a 12 30 0.0
>>> 12.5
```

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve my preferred approach using argparse? 
Note: I want the auto-generated argparse help text to look sensible.

Full code example:

```
import argparse
import sys

def dms_to_decimal(deg,min,sec):
    assert float(min) < 60.0, 'Mintue value: %s must be less than 60' % float(min)
    assert float(sec) < 60.0, 'Second value: %s must be less than 60' % float(sec)
    return float(deg)+float(min)/60.0+float(sec)/(60.0*60.0)

def decimal_to_dms(deg):
    min = 60.0*(deg-int(deg))
    sec = 60.0*(min-int(min))
    return int(deg),int(min),sec

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Convert decimal degrees to dms and visa versa')
parser.add_argument('-a',dest='dms_args',nargs=3)
parser.add_argument(dest='dec_arg',type=float,nargs='?')
args = vars(parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:]))

if args['dms_args'] is not None:
    print dms_to_decimal(*args['dms_args'])

if args['dec_arg'] is not None:
    print decimal_to_dms(args['dec_arg'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with a custom action:

```
import argparse

class OneOrThree(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if len(values) == 1:
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
            setattr(namespace, 'result', decimal_to_dms(*values))
        elif len(values) == 3:
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
            setattr(namespace, 'result', dms_to_decimal(*values))
        else:
            raise parser.error('Expected 1 or 3 arguments')

def dms_to_decimal(deg,minute,sec):
    assert float(minute) < 60.0, 'Mintue value: %s must be less than 60' % float(minute)
    assert float(sec) < 60.0, 'Second value: %s must be less than 60' % float(sec)
    return float(deg)+float(minute)/60.0+float(sec)/(60.0*60.0)

def decimal_to_dms(deg):
    minute = 60.0*(deg-int(deg))
    sec = 60.0*(minute-int(minute))
    return int(deg),int(minute),sec

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    usage='%(prog)s deg [minute, sec]',)
parser.add_argument('dms_args', nargs='+',
                    type=float,
                    action=OneOrThree,
                    metavar='deg [minute, sec]',
                    help='Given one arg, returns dms. Given three args, returns deg')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.result)
```

---

Running the above produces behavior like this:

```
% test.py 12.5
(12, 30, 0.0)

% test.py 12 30 0.0
12.5
```

If the incorrect number of arguments are supplied an error is raised:

```
% test.py 12 30
usage: test.py [-h] dms_args [dms_args ...]
test.py: error: Expected 1 or 3 arguments
```

The help message looks like this:

```
% test.py -h

usage: test.py deg [minute, sec]

positional arguments:
  deg [minute, sec]  Given one arg, returns dms. Given three args, returns deg

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
```

Comment: A custom action like this is good for testing the number of arguments, but it does nothing to the usage message.  In cases like this it is best to write your own usage.